# Error (can only concatenate list (not "NoneType") to list) when trying to create KCSB (kusto connection) in Azure Python Runbook

Tags: python, azure-data-explorer, nonetype, azure-runbook

I'm using an Azure Python Runbook. Trying to do something simple, connect to a Kusto endpoint and run a query.

I am able to make this code work in local environment, but not from the actual runbook.  Always running into the 'nonetype' error.

Any ideas?

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import azure.kusto.data
from azure.kusto.data import KustoClient, KustoConnectionStringBuilder
from azure.kusto.data.helpers import dataframe_from_result_table
from azure.identity import ManagedIdentityCredential
from azure.kusto.data import KustoClient, KustoConnectionStringBuilder
from azure.kusto.data.exceptions import KustoServiceError
from automationassets import get_automation_variable
from http.client import HTTPConnection
import http.client
import socket



#Function getServiceInfoFromKusto, runs a kusto function and stores the results

#set the default socket options to 0
socket.setdefaulttimeout(0)

def getServiceInfoFromKusto():
    # Get the Kusto connection string from azure runbook variable
    kcsb = KustoConnectionStringBuilder.with_aad_device_authentication(get_automation_variable('KUSTO_CLUSTER'))
    # Create a Kusto client
    client = KustoClient(kcsb)

    # Execute a query that returns a result table
    response = client.execute(get_automation_variable('KUSTO_DATABASE'), get_automation_variable('KUSTO_QUERY'))
    # Convert the result table to a Pandas DataFrame
    kustodf = dataframe_from_result_table(response.primary_results[0])
    return kustodf

#print results of kustodf
def printKustoDF(kustodf):
    print(kustodf)

getServiceInfoFromKusto()
printKustoDF(kustodf)
```

**Error:**

```
Failed
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "C:\Temp\3cvjyhyz.ugm\15fde0e7-4917-4274-b6cf-b1c5dbf6419b", line 58, in <module>    kustodf = getServiceInfoFromKusto()  File "C:\Temp\3cvjyhyz.ugm\15fde0e7-4917-4274-b6cf-b1c5dbf6419b", line 46, in getServiceInfoFromKusto    client = KustoClient(kcsb)  File "C:\WPy64-3800\python-3.8.0.amd64\lib\site-packages\azure\kusto\data\client.py", line 606, in __init__    socket_options=HTTPConnection.default_socket_options + self.compose_socket_options(), pool_maxsize=self._max_pool_sizeTypeError: can only concatenate list (not "NoneType") to list
```

I've tried including: HTTPConnection.default_socket_options = []
but have the same error with or without that line.

Comment: To connect to a Kusto endpoint from an Azure Python Runbook, you can use the azure-kusto-data package. Here is an example code snippet that shows how to connect to a Kusto endpoint and run a query:

Comment: from azure.kusto.data import KustoClient, KustoConnectionStringBuilder
from azure.kusto.data.exceptions import KustoServiceError

cluster = 'https://<cluster-name>.<region>.kusto.windows.net'
database = '<database-name>'
client_id = '<client-id>'
client_secret = '<client-secret>'
authority_id = '<authority-id>'

kcsb = KustoConnectionStringBuilder.with_aad_application_key_authentication(cluster, client_id, client_secret, authority_id)
client = KustoClient(kcsb)

query = "<your-query>"
response = client.execute(database, query)